# everything is setted,but riak start failed

Tags: linux, riak

[root@TrafficVault-192-168-1-131 riak]# service riak start
Starting riak: riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@TrafficVault-192-168-1-131 riak]# riak console
config is OK
-config /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/app.2017.02.14.14.14.46.config -args_file /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2017.02.14.14.14.46.args -vm_args /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2017.02.14.14.14.46.args
Exec:  /usr/lib64/riak/erts-5.10.3/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib64/riak/releases/2.2.0/riak               -config /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/app.2017.02.14.14.14.46.config -args_file /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2017.02.14.14.14.46.args -vm_args /var/lib/riak/generated.configs/vm.2017.02.14.14.14.46.args              -pa /usr/lib64/riak/lib/basho-patches -- console
Root: /usr/lib64/riak
Erlang R16B02_basho10 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [async-threads:64] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true] [frame-pointer]

[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,riak_core,{bad_return,{{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{function_clause,[{orddict,fetch,['riak@192.168.1.130',[]],[{file,\"orddict.erl\"},{line,72}]},{riak_core_capability,renegotiate_capabilities,1,[{file,\"src/riak_core_capability.erl\"},{line,441}]},{riak_core_capability,handle_call,3,[{file,\"src/riak_core_capability.erl\"},{line,213}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,585}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,239}]}]},{gen_server,call,[riak_core_capability,{register,{riak_core,vnode_routing},{capability,[proxy,legacy],legacy,{riak_core,legacy_vnode_routing,[{true,legacy},{false,proxy}]}}},infinity]}}}}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: /var/log/riak/erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,riak_core,{bad_return,{{riak_core_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{function_clause,[{orddict,fetch,['riak@192.168.1.130',[]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the node was renamed after being started.  There is a section in the documentation to deal with that: http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/using/cluster-operations/changing-cluster-info/#rename-single-node-clusters

Basically, if this is a single-node setup, delete the ring file and restart.  If you have already formed a cluster and added data, you will need to use `riak-admin reip` and/or `riak-admin cluster force-replace` (in the same page in the doc above)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have changed the IP address from `192.168.1.130` to `192.168.1.131`. Please ensure `/etc/riak/riak.conf` has been changed to reflect this - there will be IP addresses in that file.

Comment: Thank you very much! i want to ask that in the file:/etc/riak/riak.conf.The nodename=riak@**** should use the IP of the Ops or the IP of the Riak?